# How to access URDF info inside a transmission interface?

Tags: ros2, urdf, ros2-control, transmission

I'm trying to write a custom transmission interface for ros2 control for the robotiq 3f, and I need access to the joint limits defined by the urdf, but the Joint handle does seem to contain that info, and I can't see any way to access the URDF. Any suggestions or good workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I already had the same problem as you are describing: But this is not yet possible directly from ros2_control side. I'll bring that up on the roadmap for the next LTS version Jazzy. (We recently added this for controllers in the rolling version.)
In the meantime, the only workaround is to add a node to your hardware_component and parse the URDF from a parameter or add a subscriber to the /robot_description topic.*

Edit: I was wrong, this should be possible already since [this PR](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/pull/709/files): The full URDF is inside `hardware_info.original_xml`.

Comment: @peter-mitrano I updated the description, this IS already possible.